# Azure Log Analytics KQL - Last log received (most recent)

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

I've just started out in KQL and am struggling to find a way to get the most recent status/value for a particular log value. We have a lot of machines and I just want to know the most recent value reported, something like this (pseudo-code). So I end up with a list of distinct computers and their status and when they last reported.

For example:

```
ProtectionStatus
| project Computer, ProtectionStatus, OSName, TimeGenerated
| where TimeGenerated = MostRecent
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `arg_max()` (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)).

Use it as follows:

```
ProtectionStatus
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, ProtectionStatus, OSName) by Computer
```

This reads like this: return records from the `ProtectionStatus` table, where for every value of `Computer` I want to see the values of `ProtectionStatus` and `OSName`, where `TimeGenerated` has max value (for this specific `Computer`).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JohnSmith, please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Ive accepted, my apologies, didnt know it was needed.